# Prevent pickle from including filename / module name in its structure?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, pickle

I recently ported a Python 3.8 script up to AWS Lambda functions. Due to the 15 minute timeout in Lambda functions, I have to pass the data to another Lambda to finish execution.

Note: **I'm not changing to another AWS service** to solve this.

Simply create a class, put all the data in it, and pickle it to a file for the other Lambda to read.

*Lambda 1 looks as follows:*

```
#filename: lambda_function.py

import pandas as pd
import pickle, boto3, json, s3fs

class DataToPass():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False) #auth set in Lambda permissions
        self.df = None
        # ... etc
        
    def my_method(self,variable):
        return pd.DataFrame([self.data + variable]) 
    
    def to_pickle(self, filename):
        pickle_filename = self.S3_FOLDER_PICKLES+filename
        with self.s3.open(pickle_filename, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self,f)
        return pickle_filename        

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # do lots of calcs, create class instance, get all data in instance
    data = 1 + 1
    A = DataToPass(data)
    A.df = A.my_method(6)

    # the class data are in the instance "A", and it is ready to be pickled
    pickle_filename = A.to_pickle('saved_instance.pickle') #NOTE: method above

    # now invoke other (async, in this case) Lambda and tell it where
    # to find the pickle file with the class instance data:
    input_params = {"PICKLE_FILENAME":pickle_filename}
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName = 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:YATAYATAYATA',
        InvocationType = 'Event',
        Payload = json.dumps(input_params)
        )
    
    return "COMPLETE"
```

Everything above works GREAT! It saves the pickle, and my second Lambda reads it in just fine.

The problem is that I sometimes need to pull the pickle file down to debug or verify the data. When I download it (refer the below mentioned code block) from s3 and try to open it on my computer, e.g. in Jupyter Notebook (also running Python 3.8), ***it raises an error that indicates the file that the class was created in, *lambda_function.py* (see below), was pickled along with it.***

```
# jupyter-notebook filename: CheckPickleFiles.ipynb

import pickle

with open('saved_instance.pickle','rb') as f:
    A = pickle.load(f)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2b6241ac51f7> in <module>
      2 
      3 with open('saved_instance.pickle','rb') as f:
----> 4     A = pickle.load(f)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lambda_function'
```

I've read other answers about this, but none actually try to solve the problem on the **front end** i.e. *preventing the pickle from inserting the filename in the first place*.
After all, what if one of my colleagues wants to pull the pickle and check out the data? It should be as easy as my second code block above.

PS - I have tested this by creating the class in a different file, and it then says:

```
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'the_other_filename'
```

Please help, and thank you in advance.

Comment: A pickle file *never* includes code - the only way it can recreate a class instance is via the class name and module name references included in the file.  So having a same-named file with a same-named class is absolutely the only way to make unpickling work.

Comment: I see. That's disappointing. Is there perhaps a different method of saving an object that might be more flexible? Or am I missing the point perhaps?